# I want to redirect all my website traffic to "https://www.example.com/index.html"

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

If someone visits my website like:

- `example.com`
- `www.example.com`
- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`
- `https://www.example.com`

I want to redirect it to `https://www.example.com/index.html`. I tried the code below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html$1 [R=301,L,NE]
```

The above code worked fine however if visitor type `https://www.example.com` it will not redirect to `https://www.example.com/index.html` and also if visitor uses Google chrome and type `www.example.com` it will also not redirect to `https://www.example.com/index.html`.

Comment: Are you expecting URLs with a URL-path, like `/foo`? Are you using any static resources (CSS, JS, images)?

Comment: _"however if visitor type `https://www.mywebsite.com` it will not redirect"_ - and why should it, this is not missing the `www.` prefix, so your first RewriteCond does not apply, and it will not be using port 80 since it is an HTTPS request already, so your second condition does not apply either.

Comment: Hi @MrWhite,  I just want it to be full path like https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html. The reason is that for the purpose of not duplicating page when indexing by google. Because as per site audit there are two duplication results https://www.mywebsite.com and https://www.mywebsite.com/index.html. So I used redirect 301 in full path instead of canonical.

Comment: So this is a SPA? Most would generally prefer just `example.com/` rather than `example.com/index.html` - but you prefer to see `index.html` In the URL?

Comment: @MrWhite exactly

Comment: _"So I used redirect 301 in full path instead of canonical."_ - why tough? The explicit purpose of `canonical` _is_ to tell tools like search engines, which of two different URLs serving the same content, is actually supposed to be the main one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect "/" to "/index.html" (HTTPS + www)
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/index.html [R=301,L]

# Redirect non-www to www (+HTTPS)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS (any remaining URLs)
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Just the first rule satisfies the requirements outlined in your question. All the stated URLs are redirected to `https://www.example.com/index.html` (HTTPS + www).

The second and third rules are just generic canonical (www + HTTPS) redirects for anything else, including if the user requests `/index.html`.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues. You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.

---

A look at your rules...

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
>  
> RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/index.html$1 [R=301,L,NE]
> ```

Your first rule redirects to HTTP, not HTTPS, which is the intended target.

The second rule redirects *everything* (including any static assets) to `/index.html` and appends the requested URL on the end (with the use of the `$1` backreference). eg. A request for `http://example.com/foo` would be redirected to `https://www.example.com/index.htmlfoo` (in two redirects).

---

**UPDATE:**

> Every time I work in a localhost environment the localhost is affected by the HTTPS redirection. ... I have no other rules in the htaccess files, only this redirection rules only. Yes it's okay to turn off all these rules on localhost. The hostname on my local dev environment is "localhost".

To disable all these rules on *localhost* you can add the following rule first, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive.

```
# Prevent further processing on localhost
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =localhost
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

The above states... for every URL request, where the `Host` header is exactly equal to `localhost` then perform no *substitution* (as denoted by the hyphen `-`) and the `L` (`last`) flag prevents the following rules being processed.

Comment: everything is working perfectly! I understand your deep explanation of how my current codes work and how your suggested codes work.

Comment: Greetings MrWhite, I have another problem after implementing your above-suggested code. Every time I work in a localhost environment the localhost is affected by the HTTPS redirection. Is it possible to turned off redirection if request is coming from a server localhost?

Comment: @JeffreyGabisayjeff Do you have any other rules in the `.htaccess` file? Is it ok to "turn off" all these rules on localhost (since they all currently redirect to HTTPS)? What is the hostname on your local dev environment? Is it literally `localhost`?

Comment: Hi MrWhite, I have no other rules in the htaccess files, only this redirection rules only. Yes it's okay to turn off all these rules on localhost. The hostname on my local dev environment is "localhost". Like localhost/process.php. Please advise what code I have to insert in order to achieve this.

Comment: Fantastic! Save my day! This is what I am looking for. Take care MrWhite and continue helping others. God bless you!